# Hadoop : Which configuration is Good

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What is good as a hadoop configuration..

A large number of small machines each with 512 MB Ram or a small number of large machines (somehting like 2Gb or 4GB Ram)

I can choose either of the two as my nodes would be VMs..

Please share your thoughts..

Answer (score 2):

The bottlenecks are very dependent on the type of application you use. But in general, I would IMHO say that your assumption of memory is off. You should get fewer and faster mainstream machines. How each machine is configured depends on its role, but there is no way that a large number of 512 MB VMs would match even a few 12-24 GB mainstream servers with good networking/CPU and disk.

Standard high volume equipment is the way to go, but actual translates into this:

First get an efficient performance per dollar *per machine* before you go "sideways". Only going "sideways" with underpowered machines becomes much more expensive.

The cluster of inexpensive machines does not really mean "any machine" (contrary to some popular belief). The overhead of each node is really big, so adding memory, disk space and disk throughput and CPU is generally more efficient than adding the next node. This is of course only true up to the point where you are still in the "high volume hardware" category (mainstream ***fast*** servers). The last mile in clock frequency, memory and disk should be avoided.

So to answer your question, go for a few Gigabit Ethernet machines with 12 GB of RAM and a fast CPU and big fast disks. Make sure that all machines operate on a Gigabit switch.

BTW, many people recommend dual socket machines, Xeon CPUs, raided disks and 24 GB of RAM and argues that this gives the best performance/dollar for Hadoop.